# In numpy, how do I select a subset of a 2-dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a 2-dimensional, 416*416 array, and I want to shrink it to the top left corner to make a 387*387 array. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this.

I've tried variations of array[range(387),range(387)] and masking, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
A[:387, :387]
```

But what you have tried:

```
A[range(387), range(387)]
```

should work as well. (Though in simple cases the simple splicing is usually clearer and more efficient.)

Just a code example for you to think of what is going possibly wrong (i.e. there may be some other problem with your code):

```
import numpy as np

# create an array (shape 10 x 8)
A = np.arange(80).reshape(10,8)

# create a smaller array (5x4) of the top left corner
B = A[:5,:4]
```